# Interpreting odds ratios

Tags: probability

Suppose there is a state with 224 settlmenets to whose representatives I send a message randomly from either group R or group NR. The incoming reponses are like in the following matrix:

```
         R   NR   Sum
0       31   22   53
1       72   99  171
Sum    103  121  224
```

Because I had several variables of interest in the experiment, I started analysing the effect sizes in odds ratios, so they were comparable.

odds (R) = success ⁄ <sub>failure</sub>  = 0,7 ⁄ <sub>0,3</sub>  = 2,33
odds (NR) = 0,82 ⁄ <sub>0,18</sub>  = 4,56
OR (R ⁄ <sub>NR</sub> ) = 2,33 ⁄ <sub>4,55</sub>  = 0,51

which means

[1] **The odds of R to receive a response is about half (0,51) that of the odds of NR to receive a response.**

But for most people odds are a difficult concept to understand, and therefore I'd like to interpret the result in an everyday language too. So I calculate the probabilities which are

p(R = 1) = 73 ⁄ <sub>103</sub>  = 0,70
p(NR = 1) = 99 ⁄ <sub>121</sub>  = 0,82

My questions is whether it is a correct interpretation of the data if I give an estimate that [2] **about every 8th person in group R could experience differential treatment in comparision to group NR.**

(I got this result by simply dividing the probability of response in each group by ten. The ratio between 82 and 70 is like the ratio between ~ 8 and 7.)

If yes, then how is this sort of simplification called, when one tries to express effects in terms of smallest units. I tried looking at very different sources, like mathsisfun.com and Agresti's *Categorical Data Analysis* (2002), but the closest concept I could find was the difference of proportions which is, of course, not what I am doing here.

I apologise if this is a very basic question in this forum, but I find the magnitude of my results, as interpreted in terms of [1] and [2] quite counter-intuitive, and I really want to understand what I am saying.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A note about your calculations.  You are rounding your intermediate calculations and therefore losing precision or getting incorrect digits.  The odds of response for Group NR is $99/22 = 4.5$ exactly.  You instead calculated $99/121 \approx 0.82$, then $22/121 \approx 0.18$, but you have discarded too much precision in doin so, leading you to an imprecise result of $0.456$ when even a few extra digits would not have led you astray; e.g., $$\frac{99}{121} \approx 0.81818, \quad \frac{22}{121} \approx 0.18182, \quad O_{NR} \approx 4.49995.$$

Also note that a shortcut to compute the odds ratio is to write $$OR_{R/NR} = \frac{(72)(22)}{(31)(99)}.$$

As for the "non-intuitive" difference between the odds ratio of $0.516129$ and the response rates, think of a more extreme example where the response rates among both groups are very nearly $1$; e.g.,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \text{R} & \text{NR} & \text{Total} \\
\hline
0 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
\hline
1 & 101 & 120 & 221 \\
\hline
\text{Total} & 103 & 121 & 224 \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Here I have chosen the cell values such that the group (column) totals are unchanged from your example.  Now if we calculate the odds ratio, we get $$OR_{R/NR} = \frac{(101)(1)}{(2)(120)} \approx 0.42083,$$ meaning that the odds of response for group R is less than half of the odds of response of group NR, but in terms of their individual response rates, they are almost equal:  $$\Pr[R = 1] = \frac{101}{103} \approx 0.980583, \\ \Pr[NR = 1] = \frac{120}{121} \approx 0.991736,$$ meaning that about every $1$ in $100$ persons will have different responses between the two groups.

Why does this happen?  Because the odds of an event can be any positive number, whereas a probability can only be between $0$ and $1$.  The odds ratio doesn't capture the absolute difference in responses.  It looks at the relative odds of response versus non-response.

Comment: Thanks for your note conserning precision! And the example you brought up illustrates nicely the behaviour of odds ratios. I guess the point is that odds ratios don't behave intuitively when the variable of interest doesn't have uniform distribution.

Comment: And I found the answer to my (sub)question too. It's called "scaling down ratios" :-)
https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/ratio.html